# How to create Responsive HTML, CSS table?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a responsive table only with HTML & CSS that has a icon button aligned to right side when on responsive view as similar to the bellow image. The bellow code renders a responsive table, however the icon is also aligned on the next line. I want it to be aligned on right side as in image.  any one Please help on this.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* border-collapse: collapse; */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table tr {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  
}

table th {
  font-size: 15px;

  text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
    width: 100%
  }

  table thead {
    border: none;
    /* clip: rect(0 0 0 0); */
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
  }

  table tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    /* margin-bottom: .625em; */
  }

  table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: right;
  }

  table td::before {
    
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
       
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Upload Date</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
           

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td data-label="Name">John</td>
            <td data-label="Type">file</td>
            <td data-label="Upload Date">21/04/20</td>
             
              <td class="dropdown">
                <p><a id="" class="ti-more-alt"></a></p>
               <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#">View</a>
                  
                </div>
              </td>
               
          </tr>
          
          <tr>
            <td data-label="Name">John</td>
            <td data-label="Type">file</td>
            <td data-label="Upload Date">21/04/20</td>
              <td class="dropdown">
                <p><a id="" class="ti-more-alt"></a></p>
               <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#">View</a>
                 
                </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td data-label="Name">John</td>
            <td data-label="Type">file</td>
            <td data-label="Upload Date">21/04/20</td>
            <td class="dropdown">
                <p><a id="" class="ti-more-alt"></a></p>
               <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#">View</a>
                
                </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
         
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please post your code snippet, so that we can get to know what and how you are trying

Comment: post updated, please have a look.

Comment: Your image doesn't seem to show a table layout. It would be a lot easier to just build this using block/inline elements, using a table like this is actively making things harder for yourself.